# Monotouch SerializeObject randomly throws exceptions

Tags: iphone, json, serialization, xamarin.ios, json.net

This following code throws an exception once in a while, what makes it much harder to understand the problem.

```
GetFeaturedApiRequest request = new GetFeaturedApiRequest ();
 request.RequesterID = GlobalData.UserHeykuId;
 request.Index = index;
 request.RequesterIP = GlobalData.UserIp;
 try
 {
   string jsonReq = JsonConvert.SerializeObject (request);
   .
   .
   .
 }catch (Exception message)
```

**This is the stack trace** for 100% sure all the values are initialized.

Unhandled managed exception: Object reference not set to an instance of an object (System.NullReferenceException)
  at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.GetContractSafe (System.Object value) [0x00000] in :0 
  at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalWriter.Serialize (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonWriter jsonWriter, System.Object value) [0x00000] in :0 
  at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.SerializeInternal (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonWriter jsonWriter, System.Object value) [0x00000] in :0 
  at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonWriter jsonWriter, System.Object value) [0x00000] in :0 
  at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject (System.Object value, Formatting formatting, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings settings) [0x00000] in :0 
  at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject (System.Object value) [0x00000] in :0 
  at HeyKu.LoadDataFromServerManager.LoadFeaturedFeedFromServer (Int32 index, HeyKu.handleEndOfLoadData handle, Boolean isFirst) [0x00000] in :0 
  at HeyKu.LoadDataFromServerManager.LoadInitialDataFromServer (Boolean loadProfile) [0x00000] in :0 
  at HeyKu.LoadDataFromServerManager.LoadInitialDataFromServer () [0x00000] in :0 
  at HeyKu.AppDelegate.m__2 () [0x00000] in :0 
  at System.Threading.Thread.StartInternal () [0x00000] in :0

**Thanks very much for your help**

Comment: Seems to be an internal error that shouldn't happen. Are you using the Json.Net version from the Component store? (http://components.xamarin.com/view/json.net)

Comment: I'm using a one from github. you think that is the problem ?